# copy content of a file

Tags: file, copy

When you do this:

```
cp file1 file2
```

(`file2` already exists)

What actually happens behind the scene?

1) Does the content of `file1` actually get copied to `file2`?

2) Or is a new file created with the name `file2` (overriding the old one) which has same content of `file1`?

Comment: Actually run the "ls -i" command to look at the before/after inodes, too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Since you're using "cp", I assume the OS is Linux.

2) On Linux, a "file" is referenced by "inodes".  Here are two example files:

```
$ ls -li 1 2
 245728 -rw-r--r--    1 paulsm   users           8 Aug 14 14:52 1
 245729 -rw-r--r--    1 paulsm   users           8 Aug 14 14:52 2

$ cat 1
Hello 1

$ cat 2
Hello 2
```

3) Here is the result after "cp"

```
$ cp 1 2
$ ls -li 1 2
 245728 -rw-r--r--    1 paulsm   users           8 Aug 14 14:52 1
 245729 -rw-r--r--    1 paulsm   users           8 Aug 14 14:55 2
$ cat 2
Hello 1
```

You see:

a) the contents of "1" completely replace "2"

b) there is no "new file" - the inode for "2" remains unchanged from before the copy

c) the file *date* is changed along with the file *contents*

'Hope that helps .. PSM

Answer (score 0):

Usually the first. Both an index-entry as well as the file's data are written.
Yet it would help to know on what (file-)system you are (guessing linux flavour).

You would probably be aware if you were creating a junction point or symbolic/hard LINK.

Think of it like this:
Hardlink is a pointer/name, that points to a data; i.e. it's just an alternative filename; it has same inode number as the file it was created from.

Copy obviously, copy of the data; point to a different direction that file it was copyed from; has different inode number.

Also difference is in system calls, but that`s somewhat deep-diving into issue